# How do I create a constant line value across a date dimension from one date point?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a fact table joined by a Date Dimension and a Product dimension. Within the fact table, I have a date column that specifies when the product size expired and another column that specifies the product size. Ultimately I need to show the product size over time, but the logic should be such that the empty dates are currently the active product size dimension, they should be a constant line until the last date that appears (if any). If necessary, I can also populate the blanks with the present day's date. The problem here being I also need to simultaneously show products that don't have a previously expired size as a constant line across my date dimension. Every product has it's own size, but I would also like my measure to aggregate the capacity.

[image: Table Structure]

So the above fact table would ultimately look like. In the below example the measure does not aggregate them, but ideally, I'd like to create a measure that would do that.

[image: Visual]

Comment: Why do you have 4 rows on your table for Product A? should it be just 3?

Comment: Yes, it should just be three rows. there's a typo in the third row making it look like an additional one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
measure=
   var date = SELECTEDVALUE(dateTable[date])
   var expiryDate = CALCULATE(LASTDATE(table[date]), ALL(table[date]), table[date] >= date)

   Return CALCULATE(SUM(Table[Size]), ALL(table[date]), table[date] = expiryDate)
```

I wouldn't connect it to the date table, so you don't have to do the `All(...)` in my example above.